# Range slider filter without minimum/maximum values

Tags: search-facet, sxa-search

I have added a custom field in Solr **beds** and created a new **Bedrooms** facet. I am using the facets in a **Range Slider Filter**

[image: bedrooms]

I have defined the **minimum** and **maximum** values. Is there a way we should not define the **minimum** and **maximum** values and uses the original **minimun/maximum bedrooms** values in the index? I don't want to hard-code the minimum/maximum values because I don't know the minimum/maximum bedroom values in the indexes.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the definition of Range Slider SXA component this is not possible:

[image]

Because these values need to be numeric. Picture taken from  official SXA documentation -> https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/use-the-sxa-search-filter-components.html.

However, you could clone the component and try to change "backend" implementation of Controller to your needs to calculate it from SOLR values coming as output.